# IntelliJ randomly fails to load ApplicationContext for Spring JUnit Test with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I cannot paste the whole stacktrace but pretty often, unit tests that work fine through the command line and were working fine the last time through the IDE suddenly start failing when ran through IntelliJ. It is always something like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
...Long meaningless stack trace
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'serviceClass' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/MTOM
...
...Even more generic stack trace
```

...

This is especially confusing since the classes it fails to find are similar default lib classes. Adding the class it fails to find to Maven dependencies sometimes helps as a duct-tape solution but it is usually a different class each time, even though the issue is basically the same. What could cause this?

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be appreciated, otherwise it would be impossible to get help with this issue.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the minimal example in my case is a massive API. Only thing I have got to go off of is the kind of classes IntelliJ fails to find but compile fine through command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Apparently IntelliJ default JRE was set to use Java 10 but system default was Java 8. Switching it to Java 8 did the trick.